# How to sample a 3D raster along a 3D path (or 4D raster along 4D path)?

Tags: qgis, postgis, 3d

I have a 3d raster dataset of atmospheric variables (lat x lon x altitude). I would like to sample this raster dataset along a 3d path.

Any idea how I can achieve this, preferable with qgis or postgis or rasdaman?

**Edit:** Actually, my data is 4d (time x lat x lon x altitude), but having a 3d solution would already be great.

Comment: Could you please explain the sense in which a 3D "polygon" can be interpreted as a *path*? Do you mean that its boundary is intended as a path, or are you perhaps asking about sampling the raster throughout the polygon itself (including its interior)?  And when you use "polygon," does that presuppose (as in the conventional mathematical sense) that it is *planar*?

Comment: @whuber of course you're right, this doesn't make sense. Forget about the polygon, I simply want to sample along a 3d path.

Comment: You probably need to bake your own [trilinear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation) routine with NumPy arrays. I have a [bilinear interpolation solution](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7658/1872) for GDAL (2D) if you need inspiration.

Comment: See also [SciPy's multivariate interpolation functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html#multivariate-interpolation), although I've experience some oddities. Worth checking though.

Comment: thanks @MikeToews, I'm actually quite familiar with SciPy and interpolation ;) However, I didn't want to have to deal with projection issues etc. and thus would favour some GIS-based solution where I don't have to worry about such stuff.

Comment: the problem with "GIS-based solutions" is that they are really tied to 2D projections that use a 2D affine transform matrix to map from pixel coordinate to global coordinate (e.g., [GetGeoTransform](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#af9593cc241e7d140f5f3c4798a43a668)). You'd need to apply a 3D affine transform instead.

Comment: I've done this in R if you want to start looking beyond your stated software. The stuff I have is *very* specific to a particular 4D data set, but it wouldn't be too hard to adapt. Adding transformations for xy is also pretty straightforward. Want to expand on what the "projection issues" are?

Comment: @mdsumner Any chance we could get you to post your R solution? I'm sure you would find support for the answer and then we could get this question off of the 'unanswered list'. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some linear interpolation stuff like this?

```
    # -----------------------------------------------------------
    # Pseudo code adopted from R
    # -----------------------------------------------------------
    # Linear interpolation of a 3D line segment in a fixed time interval
    # startT Start in Time
    # startX Start in X
    # startY Start in Y
    # startZ Start in Y
    # endT   End in Time
    # endX   End in X
    # endY   End in Y
    # endZ   End in Z
    # steps  if == 0 steps are calculater from by the time interval
    # -----------------------------------------------------------
    dataFrame function sampleLineTime4D(
       int startT, int endT, 
       double startX, double endX, 
       double startY, double endY, 
       double startZ, double endZ, 
       int steps=0) {

      # gradient
      double dt = endT - startT;
      double dx = endX - startX;
      double dy = endY - startY;
      double dz = endZ - startZ;
      if (steps == 0) steps = dt;

      # relative stepsize
      double st = dt / steps;
      double sx = dx / steps;
      double sy = dy / steps;
      double sz = dz / steps;

      # definition of an empty vector set for T X Y and Z
      Vector<double> vx = new Vector();
      Vector<double> vx = new Vector();
      Vector<double> vy = new Vector();
      Vector<double> vz = new Vector();

      # Iteration over te steps
      for (int s=0; s<steps; s++) {
        vt.add(startT+st*s);
        vx.add(startX+sx*s);
        vy.add(startY+sy*s);
        vz.add(startZ+sz*s);
      } # Ende der schleife 

      return (dataFrame(t=rt, x=rx, y=ry, z=rz));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly load this raster data into Rasdaman (using Postgresql as the underlying database), then use either the Petascope interface to provide a WCS/WCPS service and query the data that way, or use the internal RASQL query language to do the same querying.  See the [Jacobs University pages](http://standards.rasdaman.org/) for examples of using Rasdaman for multi-dimensional data.

The details of how to do this are a little convoluted to detail here, but the Rasdaman development community is very active, and there is plenty of 
[documentation](http://www.rasdaman.org/).